# How to print first two data in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I got o\p like below

```
Array ( [0] => SB_BL [1] => SB_BXL [2] => SB_GL [3] => SB_GXL )
```

In that i need o\p like below structure

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>SB_BL</td> <td>SB_BXL</td></tr>
  <tr><td>SB_GL</td> <td>SB_GXL</td></tr>
  </table>
```

```
        @for($r = 1; $r <=sizeof($x); $r++)
        <td>

        <?php $i=1; ?>
        @foreach($pro_code as $key=>$val)
        @if($i % 2 != 0)
        <input type="text" name="pro_code[]" value="{{ $val }}">
        @else
        <input type="text" name="pro_code[]" value="{{ $val }}">
        @endif
        @endforeach
        <?php $i++;?>
        </td>

        @endfor
```

The for each is placed inside a for loop, the loop execute two times already, nw wt can i doo

Comment: what did you try a little bit !! Get code

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Do you use Blade for your templates (since the question has a laravel tag)?

Comment: i'm using this for laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the iteration of your loop and print as follow

```
$i=1;
echo '<table>';
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
    if($i % 2 != 0) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$val.'</td>';
    } else { 
        echo '<td>'.$val.'</td></tr>';
    }
    $i++;
}
echo '</table>';
```

You can see a live sample here http://codepad.org/9xeiXJre

Comment: bt the foreach placed inside a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Increment your counter variable within a loop and then, if current item is greater than 2, simply exit the loop and you're done. You have just this example, since you provided no code.

Answer (score 0):

There a PHP function for [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) for Split an array into chunks of certain elements. You can Split by 2 elements and put it into a foreach loop and print out the values.

Here Example for Raw PHP:

```
$split_arr=array_chunk($main_array,2); //$main_array=Array ( [0] => SB_BL [1] => SB_BXL [2] => SB_GL [3] => SB_GXL )

echo "<table>"; //table wrapper
foreach($split_arr as $item) {
    echo "<tr><td>$item[0]</td> <td>$item[1]</td></tr>"; //row with 2 items
}

echo "</table>"; //table end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer @Fabio provided is correct for plain php. But since the OP uses Laravel, and Laravel uses Blade template engine, here is a representation in Blade syntax as well:

```
<table> 
  <tr>
  @foreach ($arrOutput as $i => $element)
    @if($i > 0 && $i%2 === 0)
        </tr><tr>
    @endif
    <td>{{$element}}</td>
  @endforeach
  </tr>
</table>
```

Maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `for` loop to print this

```
<?php 
$input =array('SB_BL','SB_BXL','SB_GL','fSB_GXL');
echo '<table>';
for($i= 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
    $v = $i+1;
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$input[$i].'</td><td>'.$input[$v].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $i++;
}
echo '</table>'
?>
```

This will output

```
SB_BL   SB_BXL
SB_GL   fSB_GXL
```